# Dynamic allocation of memory to arrays in C from another static array gives garbage values

Tags: c, memory-management, scheduling, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a C program for the FCFS scheduling algorithm.  I have been trying to dynamically allocate an array that contains the process ids stored in another static integer array.

Here's my code:

```
int pid[number_of_processes]; // Stores IDs of all processes

//Storing IDs of all Processes
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
     pid[i] = numberArray[i];
     printf("PID %d\n", pid[i]);
   }

int *ptr;
ptr = (int *)malloc(number_of_processes * sizeof(int));

for(int i =0; i< number_of_processes; i++){
  ptr[i] = pid[i];
  printf("PTR of %d is %d\n",i,ptr[i]);
}
```

**Values in pid[] are {4,1,2,3,5}** | 
**number_of_processes = 5**

**The output that I'm getting is:**

```
PTR of 0 is -395230048
PTR of 1 is 4
PTR of 2 is 100
PTR of 3 is 15
PTR of 4 is 5
```

**Expected Output is**

```
PTR of 0 is 4
PTR of 1 is 1
PTR of 2 is 2
PTR of 3 is 3
PTR of 4 is 5
```

Comment: why `i+=4` rather than `i+=1`in the first `for`, and why starting at index 1 rather than 0  ?

Comment: @bruno `pid` is an array that contains integer values of process ids e.g. `pid[5] = {4,1,2,3,5};`  The Number of Processes is 5, and what I want to do is to dynamically Store the values of `pid[5]` to `int *ptr`

Comment: the last `for` in your code is ok to do that, the problem concerned the first `for` but you edited your question

Comment: This question doesn't make sense anymore after the edit. Surely the output would have changed by fixing the for-loop.

Comment: You're iterating over `n` in the first loop and over `number_of_process` in the second loop. You can use `memcpy` to copy arrays.

Comment: My guess is that `numberArray[i];` does not have what you think, or `pid[i]` are corrupted by memory errors.  Can you post the whole file so some can compile/run/debug it for you?